# will Camera.Parameters:: setRotation rotate the image taken by samsung s2 camera?

Tags: java, android, layout, camera

Galaxy S2 takes portrait photos and add them `ORITENTATION_ROTATION_90 exif tag`.

Thus When I upload a photo to my server it is presented in landscape.

I'm using min API 8.

I'm confused, and I'll appreciate if somebody will explain.

1) I have tried:

```
     ExifInterface exif;
        try {
          exif = new ExifInterface(imageFilename);
          int orientation =
              exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
          exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
              String.valueOf(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270));
//also tried ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_UNDEFINED)
          exif.saveAttributes();
          orientation =
              exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
          boolean b = orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

        } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but it didn't help. The attributes were changed, but the image is still in landscape.

2) My current solution:

Create an new rotated bitmap in the client side.

But it might be costly.

3) Another suggested solution:

> Camera.Parameters:: setRotation
>
> ... The camera driver may rotate the picture and the EXIF thumbnail.
>   If the Jpeg picture is rotated, the orientation in the EXIF header
>   will be missing or 1 (row #0 is top and column #0 is left side).

and then i saw this code:

```
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
   if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;

   int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
         .getRotation();
   int degrees = 0;
   switch (rotation) {
     case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
     case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
     case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
     case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
   }

   parameters.setRotation(degrees );
   mcamera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

Will (3) work for my needs?

Another friend in stackoverflow said only (2) will work for me

but i couldn't understand why.

Comment: I [answered #1 already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23685042/115145). #3 definitely will not work for all devices. As the documentation states, the "camera driver *may* rotate the picture" (emphasis added). Whether it works for your particular S2 I cannot say. Note that Samsung releases several devices for major monikers like "Galaxy S4", so your particular Galaxy S2 may differ in behavior from other Galaxy S2 devices that are different products.

Comment: thanks. But I guess it will work on devices where the driver already make this problem? (creating and taking exif tag under consideration). no?  can we move to chat?

Comment: "But I guess it will work on devices where the driver already make this problem?" -- I am sorry, but I cannot clearly parse that sentence. Writing a camera app is very complex, and there are lots of broken devices out there, beyond just standard variations in behavior. That is why I am writing [a library that handles all of these edge and corner cases](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/). So far, the logic I have in my `ImageCleanupTask` to handle fixing up the images works for every device that I have tried.

Comment: I meant to say it might be that camera driver that puts "ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90" exif tag will be the same driver that acts properly on `setRotation()`. no?

Comment: You certainly need that `setRotation()` code. That's what teaches the camera driver what to do with the image. Whether the camera driver adds the EXIF tag, or actually rotates the image, is up to the device manufacturer.

Comment: so in conclusion, if i use "setRotation" - the preview surface is as expected, but the image is saved with exif rotation tag according my demand? meaning if the device would usually add 90_rotation tag I'll add 270 and the actual exif tag will be "noraml" or "0_rotation"? but sometimes that driver will ignore this and will still put "90_rotation" which is its native exif tag for that device?

Comment: At this point, I give up. I solved all of these problems a while ago in my library and forget all of the details.

Comment: thanks, but i cannot use 3rd party lib in my app. thanks for all the effort anyway